# Split the lines of record in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have below data in my report footer b section.

**Container No**

```
12344, ABC12341234, BNMKLO00, CAIU86284560, CAIU8628757,
DEF34190000, DES23457, DF3134, DF347900, DFRT56990,
DSE234661, FGR450000, GHM890000, KLM1230992, KLO900123,
PLO67799, QSAW12345, QWE123456, RT56000, RT560012WE,
SAW12344, SDQ123456789, TYHYH667000, TYT5612334,
VBGT6787900, VFR3400001, WHLU1234, WHLU5420938,
WHLU5581193, WQR6790000, XCDER40000
```

This `containerNo` list display in one field as well as I do in sql statement.

I want to display the maximum line of records as long as it was fit until to bottom of page, then the remainder line of records will be continue on the next page.

So, the output should be like:

--Page 1 of 2

Container No

```
12344, ABC12341234, BNMKLO00, CAIU86284560, CAIU8628757,
DEF34190000, DES23457, DF3134, DF347900, DFRT56990,
DSE234661, FGR450000, GHM890000, KLM1230992, KLO900123,
PLO67799, QSAW12345, QWE123456, RT56000, RT560012WE,
SAW12344, SDQ123456789, TYHYH667000, TYT5612334,
```

--Page 2 of 2

Container No

```
VBGT6787900, VFR3400001, WHLU1234, WHLU5420938,
WHLU5581193, WQR6790000, XCDER40000
```

How can I do that without using a sub-report and group?

Comment: have you used `Can Grow` option?

Comment: @Siva It done alraedy but, I have some problem in my subreport > detail section.